# add multi type currency and than getting total of each type

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table `transaction` having field  `s_no,amount`,`transaction_type("Debit","Credit")`,symbol.

I want to sum all amount for debit and also sum of amount for transaction_type credit against each symbol i.e $,Rs,AED currency symbol.
And at the end total that
is `debit-credit`.

I tried this one:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a simple `GROUP BY` solve your issue?

```
SELECT `symbol`, SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'Debit', `amount` * -1, `amount`)) amount
FROM `transaction`
GROUP BY `symbol`
```

Obviously you'd want to adjust your indexes to support this, probably on (`symbol`,`amount`)

Comment: <b>@calcinai with Debit values are incorrect i do not know when i changed it to Credit that my problem solved. thanks @calcinai